# Improving a photo's quality using gimp

Tags: gimp, pixel, posters

I have this image which is already of poor quality for an image on AO paper. I was trying to sharpen the image but it doesnt help. I have no expertise in image editing so it was quite frustrating for me. Any advice or help would be very much appreciated :)[image]

Comment: At that size, for a raster image, you really can't do a whole lot. You may do better merely recreating it at a better resolution or in vector form.

Comment: I don't see a problem with quality. It may have a problem of size (not enough pixels for the intended print size)(is the sample the actual size of the image in pixels?). If this is really a problem of a small image, it is best redrawn using a vector editor (see Inkscape), using the scaled up (but blurry) initial image as a model. It can then be printed at any size without any quality loss.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Just a couple of things to say: First, it's not a photograph, but a graphic. It's not poor quality, it's just tiny and low resolution. GIMP can't fix it, nor any raster software for that matter. The only real way to improve such a small image would be to recreate it from scratch. It could be done easily using vector software like Inkscape which is also free and Open Source).

Comment: There's a nice simple Inkscape tutorial for [making bar charts here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-k85AABbIdA)